# Creating a 'textarea' like 'canvas' element in (X)HTML?

Tags: html, xhtml, canvas, textarea

I'm trying to set up a full-page text-editor using (X)HTML, and am exploring several ways of going about this. I've got several working solutions using more conventional methods such as `textarea`, but, partially out of curiosity, and partially out of trying to find solutions to certain shortcomings of these more conventional methods, I was wondering if it were possible to create a `textarea` like `canvas` element using (X)HTML, and, if so, how?

Comment: Something like MS paint?

Comment: A Mozilla Labs project did that. http://mozillalabs.com/skywriter/

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you've tried so far, and in what way it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [google svg editor](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.4/editor/svg-editor.html).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.